# Match similar long strings in PostgreSQL and to have it tell me how similar they are

Tags: python, postgresql, pattern-matching

I'm doing a hobby project in Python (a language to which I'm new, in addition to being an amateur programmer) and one part of my project needs fuzzy lookups in a database. I chose Postgres. I imported **pg_trg** as that seemed to be a popular extension for looking up similar strings.

To find similar strings, I'm using the following query

```
SELECT * FROM database WHERE SIMILARITY(q,'whatever long string I have') > 0.6 ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1
```

Note the last part where I only want it to return one answer at random as long as it's 60% alike to my queried string. Only returning one answer is by design.

I've played around with the similarity threshold, but it's not very good with long strings. Of course, one could argue what constitutes "similarity". Which brings me to my first question…

*What's the best way of comparing longer strings in a Postgres database, and find the one most similar to the input?*

And for my seconds question…

*How do I make it return how similar said match is? I only know it's more similar than 0.6, but by how much?*

Comment: Your example of long string is not very long.  If you don't want to show actual long stings, please give us stats on distribution of lengths, or at least an average.

Comment: Similarity among strings is a domain-specific task.  Are these English phrases, like your example?  DNA sequences?  Chemical line notation?

Comment: By long, I mean full sentences of up to say 200 characters, averaging at 50. They’re phrases in English.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect pg_trgm to work reasonable well for this, if the strings being compared (the database strings, and the query string) are of similar length.  If they are not, perhaps you would want the so-called "word similarity" features.

But I don't think this can be answered in the abstract, we would have to dig into examples of actual phrases which you think are mis-scored.

To see the similarity, you would just repeat the function in the select-list as well.

```
SELECT *, SIMILARITY(q,'whatever long string I have') FROM database 
    WHERE SIMILARITY(q,'whatever long string I have') > 0.6 ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1
```

However, that way of writing it can't use a trgm index (although an index may not be all that useful anyway for similarity queries on long strings).  To do that, you would have to re-write it into `%` form:

```
set pg_trgm.similarity_threshold = 0.6;
SELECT *, SIMILARITY(q,'whatever long string I have') FROM database 
    WHERE q % 'whatever long string I have' ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I might be missing something but wouldn’t your first code about finding the similarity return a different result as it it was randomly selected to begin with?

Comment: Assuming "q" is a column of the table which is (oddly) named "database", all references to "q" in these queries will refer to that column from the same randomly selected row.  The random selection is only done once.

Comment: Bare with me, I'm new to this. Looking at your first example, where is the similarity numbers (which is of course over 0.6 in that example) stored for later use? I'm fetching the string using str(cur.fetchone()). How do I fetch the similarity number?